# LINUX: how to detect that ftp file upload is finished

Tags: linux, upload, ftp

In my project I have a file uploading feature. Files are uploaded via FTP. I need to configure a listener that will check for new files and invoke a script only when file uploading is finished. Because if I run this script immediately after detecting the new file, it can start to process file that is not completely uploaded, which will cause an error. Can anybody tell if this is possible on LINUX and how can I do this?

Comment: Can you specify what language you'd like to use?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd try using [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify), event code IN_CLOSE_WRITE.

Comment: +1 , but its worth mentioning that some ftp servers create a hidden temporary file to receive data until the xfer is finished. I.e. `.foo-ftpupload-2837948723` in the same upload path as the target file , so you'll need to make sure your event loop can deal with that and not trigger the task until the file has actually been renamed.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. I tried inotify, but I found that it fires IN_CLOSE_WRITE in situation when file is not completely uploaded, but connection is lost (for example if I stop uploading or close FTP client). So I believe there is no way of detecting file COMPLETELY uploaded rather than using HTTP. Is this correct?

Comment: The event to look for in this case is `close_write`.

Answer (score 6):

Apache "Mina" ftp server (java) might be able to do what you want, including detecting a failed upload, as mentioned [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/mina-ftpserver-users/201003.mbox/%3C8833dc801003181257w10e57abcwc9939b71e419c957@mail.gmail.com%3E)

Quote:

> From Ftplet.afterCommand, you should
>   be able to look at the reply. For
>   those failed transfers that FtpServer
>   can detect (that causes an
>   SocketException or IOException) this
>   should be something like 426 or
>   551.

Ftplet overview [here](http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/ftplet.html), including response codes.

The afterCommand method signature:

```
FtpletResult afterCommand(FtpSession session, FtpRequest request, FtpReply reply)
```

You'd check `reply.getCode()` in your overriden method. You should subclass `DefaultFtplet` rather than implementing `Ftplet` interface from scratch.

Note that `DefaultFtplet::afterCommand` shows how to detect what client command is being responded to. You can check for `STOR` or `STOU` and reply-code `426` or `551` to detect failed uploads.

However, this may not detect an upload intentionally terminated by the client, if the client app decides to treat the transfer as though the file was just shorter than it is. In the case of a unintentionally broken connection, I think the reply-code check will work. A test could be to kill the client app, or bring down the client machine's network interface.

To handle successful uploads (your original question), you can look for the success reply-code instead, ie `226`.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [inotify](http://wiki.github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/)

It doesn't automatically watch sub directories though, so if you need to monitor many ftp accounts (or the FTP client wants to create a sub dir and upload there) you'll need to handle this yourself.

Comment: Correct. A breadth-first search (similar to `ftw()`, but breadth-first) is recommended for whatever daemon is doing the watching so no sub directories are missed as it starts.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing and stumbled on pureftpd which has an upload script feature. Sounds like exactly what was needed. Found the details here: http://www.linuxbyexamples.net/2012/10/config-ftp-server-trigger-upload-file-to-call-external-script.html

Answer (score 1):

An old one but still worth adding good ideas to.

Basically, because of the nature of the internet it's pretty difficult to detect that a file is the entire file you want. Here's what I'd do:

Have clients perform the upload to a staging directory, let's call it "upload", once the put (upload) has finished the client should then rename the file to place it in another directory let's call it "ready". If the client has some issue mid transfer, the file will never end up in the "ready" directory. So no partial uploads.

Clients should handle the upload error and retry. Most clients will carry on uploading the file without needing to send the whole thing again.

On the server side you only need to act on the files in the "ready" directory and monitor for long lived files in the "upload" directory.

For extra assurance, the csender could generate a checksum file containing the sha256 hash of the contents of the file and send that with the file. That would allow you to validate the contents  against the hash before doing anything with the file.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the HiddenStores feature of Proftpd. It keeps in-transit files hidden by prefixing them with a .in.filename.ext until they have finished uploading. Your process can then safely list the directories for completed files.

http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_HiddenStores.html